# Dplyr or Magrittr - tolower?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Is it possible to set all column names to upper or lower within a dplyr or magrittr chain?

In the example below I load the data and then, using a magrittr pipe, chain it through to my dplyr mutations. In the 4th line I use the `tolower` function , but this is for a different purpose: to create a new variable with lowercase observations.

```
mydata <- read.csv('myfile.csv') %>%
    mutate(Year = mdy_hms(DATE),
           Reference = (REFNUM),
           Event = tolower(EVENT)
```

I'm obviously looking for something like `colnames = tolower` but know this doesn't work/exist.

I note the dplyr `rename` function but this isn't really helpful.

In magrittr the colname options are:

`set_colnames` instead of base R's `colnames<-`
`set_names` instead of base R's `names<-`

I've tried numerous permutations with these but no dice.

Obviously this is very simple in base r.

```
names(mydata) <- tolower(names(mydata))
```

However it seems incongruous with the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)/[magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr) philosophies that you'd have to do that as a clunky one liner, before moving on to an elegant chain of dplyr/magrittr code.

Comment: See [@Moody_Mudskipper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) answer to learn more about `dplyr::rename_all()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `magrittr`'s "compound assignment pipe-operator" `%<>%` might be, if I understand your question correctly, an even more succinct option.

```
library("magrittr")
names(iris) %<>% tolower

?`%<>%` # for more
```

Answer (score 72):

with {dplyr} we can do :

```
mydata %>% rename_with(tolower)
```

`rename_all()` can be used for the same effect but has been superseded.

Comment: seems to be limited by the number of columns:

Comment: I don't see that with 10k columns, how many columns do you have ?

Comment: in my case 5505 col and 19425 rows but I forgot that it is a spark rdd accessed through sparklyr ….

Answer (score 25):

```
iris %>% setNames(tolower(names(.))) %>% head
```

Or equivalently use replacement function in non-replacement form:

```
iris %>% `names<-`(tolower(names(.))) %>% head
iris %>% `colnames<-`(tolower(names(.))) %>% head  # if you really want to use `colnames<-`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mtcars %>% 
set_colnames(value = casefold(colnames(.), upper = FALSE)) %>% 
head
```

`casefold` is available in base R and can convert in both direction, i.e. can convert to either all upper case or all lower case by using the flag `upper`, as need might be.

Also `colnames()` will use only column headers for case conversion.

Comment: *casefold is a wrapper for tolower and toupper provided for compatibility with S-PLUS.*

Answer (score 2):

You could also define a function:

```
upcase <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- toupper(names(df))
  df
}

library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% upcase %>% select(MPG)
```

Comment: IMHO it's best solution. I named this function `names_to_upper` (and second as `names_to_lower`), `colnames_` would look good too: `mtcars %>% colnames_to_upper %>% select(MPG)`.